# how to get the array of dictionary value count

Tags: iphone

I have one array of dictionary key value pairs but am fail to get the array of dictionary count. It was showing incompatible integer to pointer conversion NSsting..

Here is my source code

```
NSString *mCnt = [[gluClkDetailArray valueForKey:@"clkIndependentItem"] count];
NSLog(@"COUNT: %@", mCnt);
```

Pleas help me on this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You are assigning integer value to string `mCnt` that's why you faced that error....:)

Comment: the count always returns value in integer

Answer (score 2):

count returns plain integer type, not NSString object.

```
NSInteger *mCnt = [[gluClkDetailArray valueForKey:@"clkIndependentItem"] count];
NSLog(@"COUNT: %d", mCnt);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSInteger mCnt = [[gluClkDetailArray valueForKey:@"clkIndependentItem"] count];
NSLog(@"Count is: %d", mCnt);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSInteger *anyInt = [[YourLovelyArray valueForKey:@"YourSweetyKey"] count];
NSLog(@"COUNT: %d", anyInt);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSInteger *integ = [[yourArray valueForKey:@"keyvalue"] count];
NSLog(@"COUNT: %d", integ);
```

do like this :)